# MongoDB: Chain find()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In MongoDB how do you chain `find()` methods? Suppose I want to do something like this in Python/pymongo

```
query = prices.find({'symbol': "AAPL"})
if start is not None:
    query = query.find({'date': {'$gte': start}})
if end is not None:
    query = query.find({'date': {'$lte': end}})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't chain find methods. Calling `find` will return the [Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) object. You probably want to build a query and then call find:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

query = OrderedDict([('symbol', 'AAPL')])

if start is not None:
    query['date'] = {'$gte': start}
if end is not None:
    query['date'] = {'$lte': end}

cursor = prices.find(query)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `defaultdict()` instead in order to add sub-dicts to `query['date']`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really like the notion of chaining, you can easily support chaining of the `filter` expression, instead of the whole query/cursor. Something like:

```
class FilterExpression(dict):
   def __call__(self, key, cond):
       e = type(self)(self)
       e.update({key: cond})
       return e

f = FilterExpression({'symbol': "AAPL"})
if start is not None:
   f = f('date', {'$gte': start})
if end is not None:
   f = f('date', {'$lte': end})
query = prices.find(f)
```

Since `FilterExpression` is a subclass of `dict` (i.e. *IS-A* dict), you can pass it to `find` without converting it first.

Comment: Why not `def __call__(...): \ self.update(...) \ return self` ?

Comment: @Jérôme better not to change the filter in place. Suppose my function takes a base_filter and wants to add some conditions to it. Better not change caller's object.

Comment: OK. I didn't about this use case. The point is just to copy the instance.